# WinRT C++ ComPtr GetAddressOf vs &

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, directx-11

I just got started with DirectX 11.1 for Windows 8 apps and I got the following ComPtr for example:

```
ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> constantBuffer;
```

What I wonder is, what is the difference between using `&constantBuffer` and `constantBuffer.GetAddressOf()`?

Sometimes they both works fine, but sometimes using `&constantBuffer` will cause my program to crash with an access violation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you read documentation?

[GetAddressOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br244957.aspx) - Retrieves the address of the ptr_ data member, which contains a pointer to the interface represented by this ComPtr.

[Operator&](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230430.aspx) - Releases the interface associated with this ComPtr object and then retrieves the address of the ComPtr object.

Comment: Ye, I read the documentation, but didn't see the remark that it releases the interface. Now I understand why it crashed as it did, thanks!